# read until a certain line from text in fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

This is is my first question in stackoverflow. I am currently doing an assignment in reading an overall stats in a text file by only using string and vectors and fstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct weather{
    string year,month,sky,mintemp,maxtemp,totrain,y, date;
    int rain = 0,scatter = 0,partly = 0,fog = 0,clean = 0,snow = 0, most =     0,storm = 0,cast = 0;
};

int main(){
string year;
int entry = 0;
vector<weather>vw;
weather w;
ifstream w_file;
w_file.open("weather.txt");
while (w_file >> w.date >> w.sky >> w.mintemp >> w.maxtemp >> w.totrain){
    year = w.date.substr(0,4);
    cout << year << endl;

 }
 cout << entry ; //this was just to confirm how many line i have in the file
```

what I manage to print out was the years of the file. What i wanted to do is to read the data in a specific year and print out the particular year with its contents. is there anyway I can do this without using goto?

---

**The data file**

```
2012-01-01 Rain 7 13 0.28  
2012-01-02 ScatteredClouds 4 8 0.25 
2012-01-03 Rain 6 12 0.28
2012-01-04 Rain 5 10 0.28
2012-01-05 Rain 7 12 0.28
2012-01-06 PartlyCloudy 3 9 0.28
2012-01-07 PartlyCloudy 7 11 0.25  
2012-01-08 Rain 7 10 0.28  
2012-01-09 PartlyCloudy 6 12 0.25
2013-01-01 Rain 3 8 0.28
2013-01-02 Rain 2 11 0.25
2013-01-03 PartlyCloudy 9 11 0.28
2013-01-04 PartlyCloudy 8 10 0.28
```

---

**The output**

```
year = 2012
   rain = 0//rain++ if rain is found
   partlyCloudy = 0//partly++ if partlyCloudy is found 
year = 2013
   rain = 0//rain++ if rain is found
   partlyCloudy = 0//partly++ if partlyCloudy is found
```

Comment: Am posting this correctly?

Comment: could you post the format or sample content from weather.txt?

Comment: sure. 2012-01-01 Rain 7 13 0.28
2012-01-02 ScatteredClouds 4 8 0.25
2012-01-03 Rain 6 12 0.28
2012-01-04 Rain 5 10 0.28
2012-01-05 Rain 7 12 0.28
2012-01-06 PartlyCloudy 3 9 0.28
2012-01-07 PartlyCloudy 7 11 0.25
2012-01-08 Rain 7 10 0.28
2012-01-09 PartlyCloudy 6 12 0.25

Comment: im sorry if it looks messy i clearly have no clue how to post it

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a way to do this without using `goto`.  I can't think of any case where `goto` is required anymore.

Look into iterating through your vector.  A good reference is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

The code snippet example from there is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

In your case, you'll want to check each `*it` for a matching date, and then if the date matches, output the data you want from the appropriate structure.

Or, depending on how the specific date you're looking for is entered, you can put it in your existing `while` loop and not even bother with storing the other data in a `vector`.  In that case, your `while` loop may look something like:

```
while (w_file >> w.date >> w.sky >> w.mintemp >> w.maxtemp >> w.totrain){
    year = w.date.substr(0,4);
    if (year == "1974") { // or whatever the year your looking for is...
    cout << w.date << w.sky << w.mintemp << w.maxtemp << w.totrain << endl;
}
```

Given the comments you've put in below, your code is on the right track - you've read in the entire file, and have the data available to manipulate it.  What you now want is to track year, rain and partlyCloudy.  The easiest way to do that is to make another structure, and store it in a vector.  The structure would be something like this:

```
struct yeardata {
    string year; // could also be int, if you want to convert it to an ant
    int numberOfRain;
    int numberOfPartlyCloudy;
}
```

Then, when you iterate through `vw` (or, as you read the file.  You still don't really need the `vw` vector), you'll have a vector of yeardatas.  Check the vector to see if the year exists, and if it doesn't add it, with the two `int`s set to 0.  Then, increment the ints as appropriate, and print out all the data from that vector.

Since it's an assignment, that's pretty much as far as I can take you.  Good luck!

Comment: but that means it only reads for that particular of year, when i reaches the following year its stops reading and only prints out the year that it reads is it?

Comment: The second code snippet I posted would only output the data for the one year you care about.  If you need to do other things with the data, store it in the vector as you have been doing, and iterate through the vector using the first code snippet as an example to follow.

Comment: I get what you mean. But your 2nd code snippet is reads and prints for only 1974 right? But what if in the text there's another set of years and different data's to be print out ....should i apply the !f_stream.eof() so that it would be able to print the following year? if so how do i increment the current year to the following year? do i convert the year to int data type and increment it, and change to it back to string?

Comment: My second snippet prints out the data for the one year.  If you want the one after, reading in a vector and using iterators makes the most sense.  `f_stream.eof` checks if the file is done.  It's not likely to help you in this situation.  Your question confuses me, though - what exactly are you trying to have your code accomplish?  What are your inputs, and what are your expected outputs?

Comment: the sample text file:
    `2012-01-01 Rain 7 13 0.28`
    `2012-01-02 ScatteredClouds 4 8 0.25`
    `2012-01-03 Rain 6 12 0.28`
    `2012-01-04 Rain 5 10 0.28`
    `2013-01-01 Rain 3 8 0.28`
    `2013-01-02 Rain 2 11 0.25`
    `2013-01-03 PartlyCloudy 9 11 0.28`
    `2013-01-04 PartlyCloudy 8 10 0.28`

the following are the sample outputs:
   ` year : 2012 `
      ` rain = (number of occurence in that year)`
       `fog = " "`

    `year : 2013`
       `rain = (number of occurence in this year)`
       `fog = " "`

Comment: I already added your sample text file to your question.  Please also change your question to say what it's expected to do.  Are you listing the number of occurrences of rain and fog in each year?

Comment: yes it will accumulate the number of occurence of rain and fog in each and will print them out seperate according to each year in the text file.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful to you, you can accept it, upvote it, or both.